# How to autosubmit Grafity Forms on pageload but try only once if submission is not possible?

Tags: jquery, submit, gravity-forms-plugin, pageload, gravityforms

I want prefill a form using parameters and autosubmit on pageload. I'm using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('form#gform_20').trigger('submit');

});

</script>
```

That works fine but if submission fails (because the form is not complete) it just keeps trying over and over.
How can I keep the form from doing that? So how to let the submission try only on pageload?

Answer (score 0):

You can cancel the submit action by calling `preventDefault();`.

Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(event) {
    jQuery('form#gform_20').trigger('submit');
    event.preventDefault();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It still keeps retrying:

I see this error in console:

Uncaught TypeError: event.preventDefault is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (<anonymous>:4:11)
    at e (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2:30038)
    at t (jquery.min.js?ver=3.6.0:2:30340)